# How to remove Azure Table Storage entry from Azure Function?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-functions

Is there any way to delete an Azure Table Storage entry/entries using Azure Functions API? The only two operations that can be easily performed on table from Azure Functions binding are read and write, using `ICollector<T>` interface. I would like to schedule periodic cleanup of a table using a function triggered by a timer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way to delete an Azure Table Storage entry/entries using Azure Functions API? The only two operations that can be easily performed on table from Azure Functions binding are read and write, using ICollector interface.

As you said, [storage tables binding scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage#a-idstoragetablesbindingsa-azure-storage-tables-input-and-output-bindings) in Azure function are reading row(s) and writing one or more rows, if you’d like to delete entity in Azure function, you could try to [reference 
"Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage" and import namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#referencing-external-assemblies).

```
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"
using System;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;
```

and then you could write C# code to [retrieve the entity and delete it from Azure table storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables#delete-an-entity).